# LinkedIn Access Token API: Access Denied Access Token

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to request an access token with endpoint:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken
```

Body:

```
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientid}&client_secret={clientsecret}
```

But i get the following response:

```
{
"error": "access_denied",
"error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}
```

My application was accepted by our LI profile owner, Nevertheless, I still cannot get the above mentioned token. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **grant_type** of **authorization_code**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context

The **client_credentials** grant type is only for a few specific APIs, which are non-member related.

> If your application needs to access APIs that are not member specific,
> use the Client Credential Flow. Your application cannot access these
> APIs by default. Learn more about LinkedIn Developer Enterprise
> products to request permission to the Client Credential Flow.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/context